# Is there a way to store data securely on a client so that it can only be read by the client while connected to an authorising source?

Tags: file-encryption, drm, gaming

I have a difficult issue facing an online gaming social space I frequent where personal content I've made for the platform is being stolen by users.

I'm wondering if there are any solutions to make this much harder to steal work from other users.

To explain: Alice, Bob and Emile join a public session. All users do not know each other, they trust the content server but may not yet trust each other. The content server sends each user copies of each other's personal user avatars and data so they can be represented in the session.

This data is loaded in memory in the clear so it can be rendered, but memory is notionally protected by various scrambling techniques to make it a harder attack vector.

The data is also cached locally on each user's machine so that if they meet again, data does not need to be sent again from the server to save bandwidth and loading times.

However, after meeting, Emile accesses his cache and is able to extract the data, stealing the avatars within it that belong to Alice and Bob, allowing Emile to visually impersonate, misrepresent Alice and Bob or just make unauthorised use of the content.

Is there a way for the cached data to be encrypted such that it can only be decrypted in memory while Alice or Bob are connected via the network in an active session?

Comment: Why do you only want to protect offline content? Don't you have the exact same problem while online?

Answer (score 1):

Encrypting the cache is certainly possible but it is a locally enforced security measure.  That is, with enough effort, the local system can be modified to simply not do it.  Further, if something is ever decrypted for any reason it is copyable.  If it exists in memory an attacker can access, it can be copied.  GPUs do not render encrypted data well, it has to be fully decrypted at some point.

Copyright in general is a cat and mouse game of ever increasing security controls.  It's not fully solved for the likes of Netflix so the odds of whatever game solving it is pretty low.

In principle, the only reasonable method of copyright is to only send a digital asset to individuals who can be trusted to respect the copyright.  What this may look like is the avatar only being sent to people on one's friends list, everyone else sees a default skin.  Or to stop playing with people who steal digital assets.

Comment: Preventing impersonation inside the game is easier.  Although each client needs decrypted graphics data in order to render their own display, they don't need decrypted accompanying metadata.  When they try to set their own avatar, the server will know it isn't theirs and refuse to send it onward to other clients who could be deceived.

Comment: Unless I take screen capture of the avatar and then outsource someone to re-make it. Won't be perfect, but it'll most likely work.

Comment: Once you send data to a client, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too much overhead for the problem at hand, but you could digitally sign the content with a key that is associated with the account. This won't prevent someone reading the content and copying it or using it, and this only works when within the system that allows for the verification of the signature, but it would work within the game environment.

- Each user's avatar and other user-created content is signed with a private key stored in the user's account
- The system itself, and other users, could use a signature verification process to determine the signed owner of the content
- Other people could use the user-generated content, but would not be able to pass it off as their own

This is a form of DRM (digital rights management), and this has its weaknesses, and really only works within the confines of the system.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to make it much harder: encrypt the content (files) delivered by the server and provide the decryption key(s) when needed to display the content.

Basically this is what Spotify did when they launched the Spotify Web Player about ten years ago: They would serve encrypted audio files and pass the respective decryption algorithm as Javascript code via Websocket to the client (as far as I could see).

Obviously there will be ways to circumvent this mechanism, but it will increase the cost of the attacker.